# How to update project in Android Studio

Tags: android, macos

I'm trying to use the example from https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples, but I can not run the following command in terminal:
android update project --path . --target android-21

The terminal responds the following:
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

I understood that I have to use Android Studio instead. How can I do this action ("android update project --path . --target android-21") in Android Studio?

Comment: you using mac??

Comment: yes, os x 10.13.6

Comment: I don't know mac, but you definitely need to set up sdk to run this command.